# How to use SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems without selecting items?

Tags: winapi, windows-shell

I'm using [SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762232%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in order to open up a new explorer window showing a particular location ([PIDL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144089%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). I'm not interested in opening just file paths, so **I need to use a PIDL** as far as I know!

This works, however, I'm not interested in selecting any of the items in the window. If I don't pass any items to be selected, the parent folder is opened instead, as per the documentation:

> A count of items in the selection array, apidl. If cidl is zero, then
>   pidlFolder must point to a fully specified ITEMIDLIST describing a
>   single item to select. This function opens the parent folder and
>   selects that item.

**How am I able to simply open the location pointed to by my passed PIDL?**

As a test, I passed one item to be selected, pointing to a null pointer. This seems to work, but I'm afraid this might have unintended side effects. This behavior doesn't seem to be documented. Is there a better way to go about what I want to achieve, or is the way I'm using this function now correct?

Comment: I usually start explorer.exe with specific command line parameters for this. See for instance http://support.microsoft.com/kb/152457 . Note that it's very insistent on no spaces before and after the comma for root or select.

Comment: If you just want to open the folder, just ShellExecute it.

Comment: @RaymondChen I see no mentioning of PIDL in the [ShellExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153(v=vs.85).aspx) documentation. I need to be able to open virtual folders as well.

Comment: @MicroVirus In [order to open a PIDL through the command line](http://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/windows/shell/explorer/cmdline.htm) I'd have to push the PIDL into shared memory, [which seems deprecated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762107(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: `ShellExecute` was shorthand for "the `lpIDList` member of the `SHELLEXECUTEINFO` structure which you pass to `ShellExecuteEx`." Sorry for leaving off the `Ex`.

Comment: @RaymondChen You still have a chance to write that up as an answer. ;p Otherwise I will in a second, I'm finding out the correct way to call `ShellExecuteEx` now when using a PIDL, since its parameters don't seem straightforward.

Comment: @RaymondChen I keep getting errors. Should InvokeIdList be used, should a verb be set, what about show? If you know the correct parameters, posting that as an answer would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`SHOpenFolder**AndSelectItems**()` should be a good indication that this is the wrong function for you to use.  If you just want to open the folder, use [`ShellExecuteEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762154%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead, eg:

```
SHELLEXECUTEINFO sei = {0};
sei.cbSize = sizeof(sei);
sei.fMaask = SEE_MASK_IDLIST;
sei.hwnd = ...;
sei.lpVerb = TEXT("explore"); // <-- not "open"
sei.lpIDList = ...; // <-- your pidl
sei.nShow = SW_SHOW;

ShellExecuteEx(&sei);
```

Comment: +1. @Remy Lebeau: ShellExecuteEx supports pidl, if my memory serves.

Comment: The question specifically asks for PIDLs. I know how to open a path, but not all PIDLs point to paths ...

Comment: @Xearinox From [a quick look at the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762154(v=vs.85).aspx) that seems to be the answer. If you post it I will accept after I tried it out.

Comment: @Xearinox 'Just' calling `ShellExecuteEx` doesn't seem all too straightforward. Am messing around with the parameters but I find the documentation confusing. Right now I get an error _"the file does not have a program associated with it for performing this action"_. Verb is set to "open", type to idlist, pidl to the desired pidl which worked for the command in OP, show to normal, and structsize to the struct's size.

Comment: @Xearinox: `ShellExecute()` does not support PIDLs, but `ShellExecuteEx()` does. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @StevenJeuris: you have to use the `explore` verb, not the `open` verb.

Comment: It seems working too when the verb is set to `NULL`.